# Media Player Problem

Tags: android

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

    public void onClick(View v){
               if(mp2.isPlaying()==true)
                       {mp2.stop();
                        mp.start();

                       }
               else
               mp.start(); 


           }      

        });         


        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

            public void onClick(View v){
                if(mp.isPlaying()==true)
                {mp.stop();mp2.start();}
                else
               mp2.start(); 

           }  

        });
```

I press the first btn and the 1st song is playing.i press the second,the first stops and the second begins.But then, as i press the first btn, the second song  stops but the first song is not playing...please help!!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not call `prepare()` (or `prepareAsync()`) and `seekTo(0)` on your original `MediaPlayer` to rewind it.

Comment: @kostas_menu: Sometime after you call `stop()` and before you call `start()` again. Here is a sample project demonstrating this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Audio

Comment: thanks for your answer!may i answer something more?if i would like to play 3+ mp3 songs can i use something like switch or i must use if as above?